# why subscribe isn't invoked

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have following issue am I doing something wrong because "done" isn't invoked:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GetPersonsService {
  url:string="https://swapi.co/api/people/"
  persons:Person[];
  headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept', 'application/json');
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getPerson(personsId){
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(`${this.url}${personsId}/`,{headers:this.headers});
  }
  getAllPersons(){
    let numberOfPersons=88; 
    const response = [...Array(numberOfPersons).keys()].map(i => this.getPerson(i+1));
    return forkJoin(response).pipe(map(value=> value),share());
  }
}
```

and MainComponent

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
      persons=[];
      constructor(private getPersons:GetPersonsService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getPersons.getAllPersons().subscribe(value=>{
          // this.persons.push(value);
          console.log("done");
        }
        );
      }
    }
```

What is going on here?Why I am not getting done in console

Comment: Can you make https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? What you have looks fine.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
core.js:6014 
swapi.co/api/people/17/:1

Comment: The issue is that I am getting the data interrupted in 17'th element. I need to handle this error but Always it outputs this error even if i add err handler

Comment: Can you update your question with how you are attempting to handle the error?

Comment: I deleted it. But I had issue I created statically 88 elements but one of the was 404 so I got 87 elements and it did output some errors

Comment: It seems your API can provide only 16 users.

Comment: check this api for value 20 and more it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create a proper array... Use Array constructor with amount of index, fill it with dummy data (null) and loop over it with map. RxJS map operator is useless.

```
getAllPersons(){
  const numberOfPersons = 10; 
  const response = Array(numberOfPersons).fill(null).map((_, i) => this.getPerson(i+1));
  return forkJoin(response).pipe(share());
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ocbfoy

**UPDATE**

It seems user 17 does not exist. In this case, please find below the update code :

```
getAllPersons(){
  const numberOfPersons = 88; 
  const response = Array(numberOfPersons)
    .fill(null).map((_, i) => this.getPerson(i+1)
      .pipe(catchError(() => of(null))
    )
  );
  return forkJoin(response).pipe(share());
}
```

Comment: Yes, because you have only 16 users. If you try to find the user as `id=17` or more it will return a 404 - Not found

Comment: It is strange. check one more time if you can:
https://swapi.co/

Comment: Chekout by yourself : https://swapi.co/api/people/17/ and https://swapi.co/api/people/16/

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.getPersons.getPerson(19).subscribe(value=>{
      // this.persons.push(value);
      console.log(value);
    }
    );
  }

Outputs

{name: "Jek Tono Porkins", height: "180", mass: "110", hair_color: "brown", skin_color: "fair", …}

Comment: @graluc Please don't post code in comments. It won't format and is generally unreadable. Instead, edit the code into your original post and add a comment indicating the update.

Comment: If the getPerson function return an error, we catch the error, and instead of return the error, we return an Observable with a value of ˋnull`. Does it make sense ?